# Encode by bit shifting got unexpected result

Tags: solidity

This is my example contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.5;
 
   
// Creating a contract 
contract Types {  
    
    function test(uint32 first) public pure returns (uint128) {
        uint32 second = 1049;
        uint64 third = 1632141235;
        
        return uint128(first | second << 32 | third << 64);
    }
}
```

When I call test(2) -> the output is 2 but I expected 30107691654193243111255179266
In the python code

```
In [58]: (2 | 0x419 << 32 | 0x61487fb3 << 64)       
Out[58]: 30107691654193243111255179266
```

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are shifting uint32 by 32 bits by definition it is zero, same with uint64.

Probably what you want is to extend uint32 to 128 bits then apply shift to the left.

I haven't tried but something like this should make it work.

```
    function test(uint32 first) public pure returns (uint128) {
        uint32 second = 1049;
        uint64 third = 1632141235;
        
        return uint128(first) | uint128(second) << 32 | uint128(third) << 64;
    }
```